# nested fork () - how to count number of processes

Tags: c, unix, fork

I get confused with this example for Fork()

```
int main(){
   if (fork()){
     if (!fork()) 
       fork();
   }
   fork();
   printif("1 ");
}
```

I count them and it'll be 12 repeated ones (how many processes will be !!!)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Your question is unclear. What do you find confusing?

Comment: I can't determine how many times it'll print "1", each time I solve it I get a new number :(

Comment: Try something simpler, like `if(!fork()) fork();` Predict the number, then run the code to get the correct answer. If you are right, try more complex code; if you are wrong then study the simple failure case to find your mistake.

Comment: `fork()` will return non-zero (and the if will execute) both in the parent and in the error condition.

Comment: @joki I don't know why my answer is not enough for you?

Answer (score -1):

Let count them:

```
int main(){
   if (fork()){          // 1
     if (!fork())        // 2
       fork();           // 3
   }
   fork();               // 4
   printif("1 ");          
}
```

When you run the program, you have the first process which will be the ancestor of all others.

`fork_1` will create a child process, the latter will have 0 as returned value. so it will continue after the if statement, then runs `fork_4`, hence another child is created.
`printf` is run twice (2) for now.

Let continue with the first process that get a non-null value, it runs `fork_2` and then gets a non-null returned value. It continues after the second if statement, runs `fork_4`. There will be two processes (the ancestor and its child process) => another two `printf`.

The child process created in `fork_2` will get a null returned value, so the if condition is true. It runs `fork_3` which gives two processes and each one of them runs `fork_4`. So printf will be run four (4) times.

At the end, printf is run 8 times. So you will get eight `1` printed.